# GCP Compute Engine outbound traffic to flow through the load balancer to internet instead of flowing directly

Tags: google-cloud-platform, virtual-machine

I have given my Load balancer IP and SSL public cert to be whitelisted to an external company to access their APIs thinking the traffic will flow through the Load balancer IP. But the traffic flows to the internet directly from the VM. Could you please help how to resolve the issue, as it is not ideal to whitelist all the VMs' IP addresses.

Also the client is using mTlS and I'm using GCP Load balancer TLS termination with GCP managed SSL certificated which adds to the problem, As I'm unable to get the private key for certificate from GCP to terminate the tls in the application instead of Load Balancer.

No Ideas to resolve yet.

Comment: 1) For your first item, that is by design. It also indicates your security team does not understand how to configure firewalls correctly (an egress connection should automatically allow the ingress response). 2) For your second item (SSL certificates), Google does not provide the certificate private key. To have the private key requires self-managed certificates that you upload to Google Cloud. 3) You mention mTLS, but no details on what problem you have. 4) Google provides several load balancers and types. Edit your post to clearly define what you have configured.

Answer (score 1):

You can use [Cloud NAT (Type: Public NAT)](https://cloud.google.com/nat/docs/public-nat) wherein you can setup a gateway that will route and translate your internal VPC/network to internet (VMs without Public IP).

For the mTLS issues, you may check [how to use mTLS](https://cloud.google.com/load-balancing/docs/https/setting-up-mtls-global-ext-https) to terminate the private key to the LB.